# Using automator to open photoshop and run external javascript

Tags: javascript, photoshop, automator

I am trying to use the Automator in MacOS to simplify for a user opening an image, and resizing/saving.  I can get the automator to properly launch Photoshop by adding in a "Open Finder Items" pointing to a specific folder where the user drags the image.  But when I add a "Run Javascript" step after this, the javascript code doesn't seem to be executing at all within Photoshop.

If I run this same code in Photoshop via the Scripts Menu, it runs fine and resizes my image.  What am I missing here to enable my Javascript to be run from Automator for Photoshop once it is open?

[image]

```
current_document = app.activeDocument;
new_width = 1000;

current_document.resizeImage(UnitValue(new_width, 'px'), null, null, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
```

Comment: You probably need to use a **Run AppleScript** action instead and try something like `tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2015" to do script "..."`, with your JavaScript replacing the ellipsis.

Comment: Have you tried targetting Photoshop in your script? (`#target photoshop`)?

Comment: You might have an easier time accomplishing this with [droplets](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html) under File>Automate>Create Droplet.  This will take a Photoshop action and create a file onto which images can be dropped.  They will automatically be processed in batch without going through Photoshop's GUI.